# I want to bypass the age restriction on a youtube video

Tags: python, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube
youtubeObject = YouTube(link,on_progress_callback=self.Download_Progress)
title = youtubeObject.title
if youtubeObject.age_restricted:
    youtubeObject.bypass_age_gate()
```

Tried to bypass the age restriction with the code above, didn't work.
Is there something i'm missing? when i print out the youtubeObject.bypass_age_gate() it returns None

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong behavior?

Comment: When you print it that's expected, cause that method does not explicitly return anything according to its docs...https://pytube.io/en/stable/_modules/pytube/__main__.html#YouTube.bypass_age_gate

Comment: @Mureinik: behaviour with bypass_age_gate() is the same as if i try without the Funktion

Comment: `bypass_age_gate()` only attempt to update the vid_info by bypassing the age gate. So likely `pytube` cannot bypass the age restrictions.